# Crystal report 208 Formula error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2008

i am working in vs 2010 with crystal report version 2008

The problem i am facing is i have a crystal report in which i have a formula filed

```
{dtDealerStockReport.Qty}*(CDBL({dtDealerStockReport.UnitPrice}))
```

The error which   i am facing is `a number currency or amount is required here`

this error is only raise when my query does not return anything but when it return the data it does not raise this error.

so how can i solve it please help me googling for many days .

Answer (score 1):

Jahanzaib,

You need to modify your formula somewhat like this.

```
IF({dtDealerStockReport.Qty} == NULL || {dtDealerStockReport.UnitPrice} == NULL )
(
    0;
)
ELSE
(
    {dtDealerStockReport.Qty}*(CDBL({dtDealerStockReport.UnitPrice}));
)
```

Problem will be solved hopefully,

Comment: this code is not working despite this is giving error in formula editor of crystal report .I think you have write this code for C# rather than formula editor of Crystal report.This is has not solved my problem

Comment: Yes, Jahanzaib, this code maybe not working in editor but its a pseudo, you can come up with the same thing according to the editor syntax, and it will work definitely I have done same several times, getting this type of error is really frustrating,

Comment: try this, IF({dtDealerStockReport.Qty} == NULL OR {dtDealerStockReport.UnitPrice} == NULL ) THEN
(
    0;
)
ELSE
(
    {dtDealerStockReport.Qty}*(CDBL({dtDealerStockReport.UnitPrice}));
)